# Can we implement dependency property in a class that does not inherit from DependencyObject? If yes, what is the difference?

Tags: wpf, dependency-properties, dependencyobject

Can we implement dependency property in a class that does not inherit from `DependencyObject`? If yes what is the difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can. This is a variant of an *Attached Property*. From [*How to Create an Attached Property*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/attached-properties-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#how-to-create-an-attached-property-):

> If your class is defining the attached property **strictly for use on other types**, then the class does not have to derive from `DependencyObject`. But you do need to derive from `DependencyObject` if you follow the overall WPF model of having your attached property also be a dependency property.

The difference begins in how you define an attached property. Instead of [`Register`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.dependencyproperty.register?view=net-5.0), you have to use the [`RegisterAttached`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.dependencyproperty.registerattached?view=net-5.0) method and you have to define the get and set accessors as static methods with the following naming convention, where `PropertyName` is the name of the attached property.

- `public static object GetPropertyName(object target)`
- `public static void SetPropertyName(object target, object value)`

Let's look at a simple example. Suppose you want create a button that shows an image and a text side-by side. Unfortunately, a `Button` only has a single `Content`. As you do not want to create a custom control right now, you try to solve the issue by creating a content template and an attached property for the path of an image to display.

```
public static class IconButtonProperties
{
   public static readonly DependencyProperty SourceProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
      "Source", typeof(string), typeof(IconButtonProperties));

   public static void SetSource(UIElement element, string value)
   {
      element.SetValue(SourceProperty, value);
   }

   public static string GetSource(UIElement element)
   {
      return (string) element.GetValue(SourceProperty);
   }
}
```

Now you can attach this property to a button in your view to define an image path. Here the attached property differs in that you define it on a different type (`Button`) using its owner type `IconButtonProperties`.

```
<Button ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ImageTextContentTemplate}"
        local:IconButtonProperties.Source="Resources/MyImage.png"
        Content="Click me!"/>
```

The last big difference is shown in the data template that uses the attached property with a `Binding`. When binding to an attached property, you have to [put the property in parentheses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/binding-declarations-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#binding-path-syntax).

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ImageTextContentTemplate">
   <Grid>
      <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
         <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
         <ColumnDefinition/>
      </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
      <Image Grid.Column="0"
             Source="{Binding (local:IconButtonProperties.Source), RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Button}}}"/>
      <TextBlock Grid.Column="1"
                 VerticalAlignment="Center"
                 Margin="5, 0, 0, 0"
                 Text="{Binding}"/>
   </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

As you can see, attached properties are invaluable for extensibility and binding in WPF. For more information on attached properties in general, you can refer to the documentation:

- [Attached Properties Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/attached-properties-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)
- [How to: Register an Attached Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/advanced/how-to-register-an-attached-property?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8)
- [Binding Path Syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/binding-declarations-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8#binding-path-syntax)
- [DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.dependencyproperty.registerattached?view=net-5.0)
- [DependencyProperty.RegisterAttachedReadOnly Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.dependencyproperty.registerattachedreadonly?view=net-5.0)